# Import AddressBook Contact Info, how to handle empty fields?

Tags: iphone, null, abaddressbook

I am importing contacts info into some textfields, but the app crashes if there are no entries for certain fields, like phone, email, etc.

**Here are my textfields:**

```
    First Name
    Middle Name
    Last Name

    Main Phone
    Mobile Phone

    Email Address

    Website
```

Suppose the selected contact doesnt have a second Phone number (in this case: Mobile Phone) or there are no URL entries for the contact. The app crashes.

```
*ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneMulti = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSMutableArray *phones = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneMulti); i++) {
    NSString *aPhone = [(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneMulti, i) autorelease];        
    [phones addObject:aPhone];
}

accountPhone1TextField.text = [phones objectAtIndex:0];
accountPhone2TextField.text = [phones objectAtIndex:1];
CFRelease(phoneMulti);
[phones release];*
```

Or if I am trying to get an email address from the contact and it doesnt exist this will crash:

```
NSString *anEmail = [(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailMulti, i) autorelease];
//Variable is not a CFString
```

***** UPDATE *****

Ended up using the following code:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef emailMulti = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
NSMutableDictionary *myEmailDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:ABMultiValueGetCount(emailMulti)];
for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(emailMulti); i++) { 
    emailLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emailMulti, i));
    email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailMulti, i); 
    [myEmailDict setObject:(NSString*)email forKey:(NSString*)emailLabel];
    CFRelease(email);
    CFRelease(emailLabel);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (phones.count > 0) {
   accountPhone1TextField.text = [phones objectAtIndex:0];
}
if (phones.count > 1) {
   accountPhone2TextField.text = [phones objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: I tried that..but NSString *anEmail = [(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailMulti, i) autorelease]; crashes becuase there are no email addresses

Comment: Are you using kABPersonEmailProperty?

Comment: yes, but for some reason, if there are no records for the Email fields...it produces a crash.

Comment: Seems strange. If you encapsulate that in "for (i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(emailMulti); i++) {}", that line shouldn't even be executed if there are no email adresses..